# Copy/Paste a formula in Libreoffice without adjusting the cells

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a formula in *Libreoffice Calc* which I would like to move (Cut and Paste) to a different cell. I would like the formula to exactly stay the same without the cells in it being adjusted by the move. I cannot use static reference (using the *$* sign) since on a different occasion I need the dynamic reference behaviour.

The only solution I have found so far, is manually copying and pasting the *text* of the formula instead of the cell itself. But this only works for a single cell and not for multiple ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when I have done a CUT & paste in Excel in the past, it transfers as is. The copy/paste will change cell references. I have not used LibreOffice.

Comment: This works in Libreoffice, too (if only for the first time that I paste the cells).

Comment: I can understand why that may happen, but I haven't tried it. A work around might be to copy/paste as many as u need in a remote section, then cut/paste each one. to the desired location

Answer (score 19):

Trick:

- Cut (ctrl + X)
- Undo (ctrl + Z)
- Paste (ctrl + V)

Since "cut-paste" works, but not "copy-paste", you can cut-paste and use the undo not to erase the old values.

Answer (score 5):

Easier, easier: I tested Daniel Möller answer, but it failed (in MacOS at least), although it opened me the way to find the solution:
**Cut** and **paste**, and **then paste the original as well**.
That fixed it, no need for macros or complex stuff.

Comment: Daniel Möller's answer worked for me in Linux but I guess yours is more robust then, as it works for me in Linux, too.

Comment: What does "paste the original" mean? Paste in the same place where it was before being cut?

Comment: In LibreOffice 7.0.6.2 on Linux: CUT (CTRL-X), then PASTE (CTRL-V) to wherever it shall go, then PASTE (CTRL-V) again to where it originally was. If you do it in the order CUT, then PASTE to where it originally was, then PASTE to wherever it shall go, things don't work out as the second PASTE updates the formula's references (weird! unexpected!). This also works for a range of cells (as expected)

Answer (score 4):

I think this solution is *easier and faster* than previous:

1. Select all cells to be copied
2. Apply <kbd>F4</kbd> as many times needed to make formulas absolute (adding $ in all sheets/columns/rows)
3. Copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>)
4. Paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>)
5. (Optional) Apply <kbd>F4</kbd> to the source and destination cells to make them relative again

Comment: The `F4` shortcut made me happy!

Comment: f4 doesn't change formula for 'sum', unfortunately.

Comment: You're the man! 

Answer (score 1):

This also annoyed me a lot so I found a workaround solution for this:

**First create a Macro which simulates a cut by first copying and then clearing the cell:**

`Tools` -> `Macros` -> `Edit Macros` -> Add the following to a module (e.g. `Module1`)

[image: Macro]

```
REM  *****  BASIC  *****

sub CutAndPaste

dim document   as object
dim dispatcher as object
document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:Copy", "", 0, Array())
dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:ClearContents", "", 0, Array())

end sub
```

**Then assign the macro to** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

`Tools` -> `Customize` -> search and select `Ctrl+X` in `Shortcut Keys` -> select `LibreOffice Macros / My Macros / Standard / Module1` in `Category` -> select `CutAndPaste` in Functions -> press `Modify` on the right upper side to assign the macro to the shortcut.

[image: assign macro to shortcut]

You can now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to cut and paste without changing the references of other cells poiting to the cut cell.